# AudioRecorder not working anymore. FileNotFoundException: Permission denied

Tags: android, audio-recording, filenotfoundexception, permission-denied

I have an audio recorder class in my application. It worked fine previously and works fine on my HTC Desire but now doesn't work on my LG. It's no longer saving the audio file to the required path. I'm thinking it's some setting on the phone that's tripping it up, but I'm probably wrong.

An error occurs when `writeAudioDataFile` instantiates the `FileOutputStream` with `filename` in the `try-catch` block

```
private String getTempFilename(){
            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
            File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

            if(!file.exists()){
                    file.mkdirs();
            }

            File tempFile = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);

            if(tempFile.exists()){
                    tempFile.delete();
            }

            return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
    }

private void writeAudioDataToFile(){
            byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
            String filename = getTempFilename();
            FileOutputStream os = null;

            try {
                    os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int read = 0;

            if(null != os){
                    while(isRecording){

                            read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

                            if(AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read){
                                    try {                               
                                        os.write(data);

                                    } 
                                    catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                            }
                    }

                    try {
                            os.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
    }

private void stopRecording(){
            if(null != recorder){
                    isRecording = false;

                    recorder.stop();
                    recorder.release();

                    recorder = null;
                    recordingThread = null;
            }

            copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(),getFilename());
            deleteTempFile();
    }

private void copyWaveFile(String inFilename,String outFilename){
            FileInputStream in = null;
            FileOutputStream out = null;
            long totalAudioLen = 0;
            long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
            long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
            int channels = 2;
            long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels/8;

            byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

            try {
                    in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
                    out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
                    totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
                    totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

                    //AppLog.logString("File size: " + totalDataLen);

                    WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                                    longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

                    while(in.read(data) != -1){
                            out.write(data);
                    }

                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                    GlobalVar appState = ((GlobalVar)getApplicationContext());
                    appState.addAudioFile(outFilename);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Error Log:

```
01-25 15:46:08.143: W/System.err(1828): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/GeneralGUI2/Study1/Music/record_temp.raw (Permission denied)
01-25 15:46:08.143: W/System.err(1828):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
01-25 15:46:08.143: W/System.err(1828):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
01-25 15:46:08.143: W/System.err(1828):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:82)
01-25 15:46:08.143: W/System.err(1828):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:134)
01-25 15:46:08.143: W/System.err(1828):     at mfc.generalguixapi8.AudioActivity2.copyWaveFile(AudioActivity2.java:239)
01-25 15:46:08.143: W/System.err(1828):     at mfc.generalguixapi8.AudioActivity2.stopRecording(AudioActivity2.java:217)
01-25 15:46:08.143: W/System.err(1828):     at mfc.generalguixapi8.AudioActivity2.access$1(AudioActivity2.java:206)
01-25 15:46:08.153: W/System.err(1828):     at mfc.generalguixapi8.AudioActivity2$2.onClick(AudioActivity2.java:126)
01-25 15:46:08.153: W/System.err(1828):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-25 15:46:08.153: W/System.err(1828):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-25 15:46:08.153: W/System.err(1828):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-25 15:46:08.153: W/System.err(1828):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-25 15:46:08.153: W/System.err(1828):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-25 15:46:08.153: W/System.err(1828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-25 15:46:08.153: W/System.err(1828):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 15:46:08.153: W/System.err(1828):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-25 15:46:08.153: W/System.err(1828):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-25 15:46:08.153: W/System.err(1828):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-25 15:46:08.153: W/System.err(1828):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the newer versions, you need an explicit WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Also, you are not allowed to write to the root of the external storage device. So, try creating a folder, and then write into that folder.

Comment: I already have that permission in my manifest file. And I am already writing to a folder, not to the root.

Comment: Can you log the path and paste it here that you are writing to?

Comment: I've just added the error log, it shows the path I'm writing to and edited the description above, the error wasn't where I thought.

Comment: Does all that direcotries/sub-directories already exist? Also, try to see the state of the external storage device.

Comment: Well getTempFilename should be making all the directories, it calls mkdir. I'll check the state of the external storage device.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, for some reason it was coming up that there wasn't an sd card. I just turned the phone off and on again.